# Remove two "limit" strings and its content

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I have this text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **wrong text:** consectetur adipiscing
>   elit. Donec quis libero erat. Integer auctor congue odio, **end of
>   wrong text** eget condimentum dui. Nam consectetur ut odio vitae
>   egestas. Ut tincidunt mi lectus, a lobortis ante malesuada ac. Etiam
>   tristique nunc finibus, **wrong text:** tincidunt lectus ac, sagittis urna.
>   Vestibulum **end of wrong text**
>   quis maximus libero, eu viverra urna. Morbi a tempor ex.

I would like to remove the phrases in bold **and its content** with *JS* and *Regex* if possible.

EDIT: Maybe I haven't made myself clear, I am asking to remove all the text between "wrong text: " and "end of wrong text" and both of the other words so the text would become like:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  eget condimentum dui. Nam consectetur ut odio vitae
>   egestas. Ut tincidunt mi lectus, a lobortis ante malesuada ac. Etiam
>   tristique nunc finibus, 
>   quis maximus libero, eu viverra urna. Morbi a tempor ex.

Comment: What you mean by **its content**?

Comment: I guess, you want to ask : For a given HTML string you want to replace the text between <b> and </b> (tags including) with 'nothing'. And the tags need to be detected by regex while traversing, is it? Do you know beforehand about the 'wrong text', is it generic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
string.replace(/wrong text:.*?end of wrong text/g, '')
```

Comment: _I would like to remove the phrases in bold and its content_  is that remove its content @Meowsome?

Comment: Yes it is, I didn't know how to call it, sorry for the misunderstanding everyone

Comment: "its content" means text between phrases that is between "wrong text:" and "end of wrong text".